# Python numpy.ndarray subclasses and zero rank arrays

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing

I am trying to create a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`.  It is very simple, and is just a numpy array with some extra attributes and methods that manipulate those attributes. For the most part, it works fine, however I have a problem when using reductions like `np.sum`.

First off, I have read both [Subclassing ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) and [Zero-Rank Arrays](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/ZeroRankArray).

It seems that when I create a subclass of `ndarray` it behaves differently with respect to zero-rank array -> scalar conversion.

In this example I just use the simplest possible derived class, one that doesn't actually do anything:

```
class XArray(np.ndarray):
    pass
x = np.eye(2)
y = x.view(type=XArray)
print type(np.sum(x)), type(np.sum(y))

<type 'numpy.float64'> <type '__main__.XArray'>
```

The former is a numpy scalar, the latter is a zero-rank array of my subclass.  Overriding `__new__` and `__array_finalize__` as documented in the array subclassing guide doesn't change this behavior.

First, my problem: this breaks object oriented-ness.  `XArray` instances cannot be substituted for `ndarray` instances transparently without breaking lots of code.

I can fix this by overriding the `__array_wrap__` method:

```
class XArray(np.ndarray):
    def __array_wrap__(self, obj):
        if len(obj.shape)==0:
            return obj[()]
        else:
            return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(obj)
a = np.sum(np.eye(2).view(XArray))
print type(a)

<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

I am fine with this, except for two questions:

1. Is this the right place to do this special case?  I can't figure out where this conversion is happening for normal numpy arrays, so I can't tell where it should happen to my derived class.
2. Is this enough to make my subclass work, or am I going to continue having compatibility problems.  Should I just abandon the idea of subclassing `ndarray`?

The goal here is to be 100 % compatible with regular numpy arrays.  It is OK and expected that some operations will lose the derived type information and return an `ndarray` base class.  I am fine with that, I just can't have code written to operate on `ndarray`'s break.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. The code itself is in ufunc_object.c, search for PyArray_Return (and right before it).

Comment: Thanks.  It helps to see where this is coming from.

To be exact, as near as I can tell this logic is happening in _find_array_wrap in ufunc_object.c.  It loops over all arguments, looking for the one with the highest priority and selecting its array_wrap method.  However, it skips any arguments that pass PyArray_CheckExact().  If it doesn't find any eligible array_wrap methods (i.e., all arguments are exact ndarrays), it calls PyArray_Return() which does the scalar conversion.